# Iterative DFS with side effect

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph, iteration

I wonder how to write the iterative DFS with side effect on traversing back?

```
function DFS(x) {
  x.in = time++          // this is obvious
  foreach (child in x.children) {
    DFS(child)
  }
  x.out = time++         // it looks problematic
}
```

where `time` is accessed by reference (so is shared with all `foo` calls).

Comment: And the link between Foo() and DFS() is .... ?

Comment: And why exactly would ths be problematic?

Answer (score 1):

use stack for iterative dfs, in case of recursive dfs you are using function call stack